# DataFormatter (org.apache.poi) drops my zeros

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I try to get the value of a cell with formatting - I get the result without zeros.

Cell value: 7654

Cell format value: 0" 0/10с"

Cell display value: 7654 0/10с

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String orderNumber = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
System.out.println(orderNumber);
```

Result: 7654 /1с

Screenshot: [Cell format value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5PTE.png)

Comment: Formula cells will be evaluated using the given `formatCellValue(Cell cell, FormulaEvaluator evaluator)` For more information [apache doc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-)

Comment: Already try it. Same result :(

Comment: I've tried to create the same thing------------------------------------------------------------


  `Cell cell = new HSSFWorkbook().createSheet("New Sheet").createRow(2).createCell(5);`
  `cell.setCellValue("7654 0/10с");`
  `DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();`
  `String orderNumber = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);`
  `System.out.println(orderNumber);`

It is not dropping zero

Comment: But cell value in my woorkbook just like: "7654" and "0/10c" it's a cell format.

Comment: I export this workbook from "1С" (Russian stuff) and have no idea why cells fills like that. I attached a screenshot.

Comment: Have you used formatting in Excel sheet then please do the following: Go to format cells> Select the Category - "custom" > Select Type - "[$-en-US]General".

Comment: If I change the format, the display value of the cell changes too. I wan't to get value of cell exactly as it's display. (with format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error in `apache poi`'s `DataFormatter` while translating the `Excel` number format `0" 0/10с"` into a `java.text.Format`. The correct corresponding `java.text.Format` would be a `new java.text.DecimalFormat("0' 0/10с'")`. But `apache poi`'s `DataFormatter` fails to translate this properly.

You should file a bug report to `apache poi` about this. But in bug report you should not give the `Excel` number format `0" 0/10с"` as the example since this contains the cyrillic letter `с` and so might lead to wrong assumtions about Unicode problems as the reason. The same issue (dropping `0` when they are contained in text parts which are in quotes) occurs using the  `Excel` number format `0" 0abc0"`.

As a workaround one can tell `DataFormatter` how single special `Excel` number formats shall be translated. For this use the method [DataFormatter.addFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#addFormat-java.lang.String-java.text.Format-).

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class DataFormatterAddFormat {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  dataFormatter.addFormat("0\" 0/10\u0441\"", new java.text.DecimalFormat("0' 0/10\u0441'"));
  dataFormatter.addFormat("0\" 0/10c\"", new java.text.DecimalFormat("0' 0/10c'"));
  dataFormatter.addFormat("0\" 0abc0\"", new java.text.DecimalFormat("0' 0abc0'"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {

     String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
     System.out.println(value);

   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

This is now able correct translating the added special number formats. Of course this is not really the final solution. That's why the hint to file a bug report to `apache poi`.